# How to debug a PostgreSQL library with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, postgresql

I wrote a library containing several stored procedures in C. I can easily load the library into postgres and execute the procedures. But I would like to debug them and check their parameters from time to time. This works perfectly with Windows but I can not manage it under Mac OSX.
After opening a query window of pgAdmin I retrieved the process id with `select pg_backend_pid();` and then execute in the same window my query having attached Xcode to the returned process id before.
The execution is not stopped at any breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the complete answer, but maybe it will be of some help.

I wrote up a little article on how I did this on FreeBSD.  It uses GDB from the command line though so like I said it might not be complete answer, but maybe it will be of help to you.

http://flycereal.blogspot.com/

Comment: Hello Bob, it took me some time to try your solution. gdb at least stops at the breakpoints, but it is sad to lose the functions and comfort of Xcode. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It's mostly likely possible to do via Xcode being a c file is a c file regardless of command line or IDE I just have never tried.

Comment: Didn't get your hint. I just debugging with GDB now. I think the most important thing is to run GDB as the same user as the database and to load the library separately with the LOAD command.